# How to debug dpkg error code (1) on upgrade of deb package?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, nginx

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie)
Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
Architecture: x86-64
```

I have several Debian servers.

Each have included in default repository `nginx` version 1.6.

After updating from original `nginx` repository, receive same error on all servers:

```
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.12.0-1~jessie_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.12.0-1~jessie) over (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.12.0-1~jessie_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/etc/default/nginx', which is also in package nginx-common 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.12.0-1~jessie_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to build `deb` package from source and still get same error.

I can't find any way to upgrade it without reinstalling the Debian to newer version.

`/var/log/dpkg.log`:

```
2017-06-26 19:56:31 startup archives install
2017-06-26 19:56:31 upgrade nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4 1.12.0-1~jessie
2017-06-26 19:56:31 status half-configured nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
2017-06-26 19:56:31 status unpacked nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
2017-06-26 19:56:31 status half-installed nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
2017-06-26 19:56:32 status unpacked nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
2017-06-26 19:56:32 status installed nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
```

I've tried to fully uninstall / purge the default `nginx` and install newer but still get error.

```
The following packages have been kept back:
libpcre3 libpcre3-dev nginx nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Become root:

```
sudo -i
```

or:

```
su
```

---

> ```
> 2017-06-26 19:56:31 status half-configured nginx:all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4
> ```

Configure packages:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

---

Fix broken packages:

```
apt-get install --fix-broken
```

---

Proceed with upgrade:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to tell what you tried when purging + reinstalling, but try this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all nginx nginx-common nginx-full
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: This command should always be avoided as it breaks you system more than it repairs.